# Measure if Tesla coli is safe

Tags: tesla-coil

I am planning to buy a Tesla coil from Alieexpress. When it arrives I wonder what are measurements I could take to make sure iit is safe. For example: how/where can I measure if the primary coil and the condesators do properly discharge after it has been switched off and how fast?

Interestingly the primary coil of the coil I want to buy is made from isolated wire (means there is some sort of PVC shielding around it just like a normal household cable would have). Is then charge/discharge of the primary an issue at all?

Comment: A tesla coil should never be considered safe.

Comment: Electricity is never safe, but we put safeguards around it and still use it. There is imho no reason why a Tesla coil should be different.

Comment: @JFritsch So what safeguards are you fitting to this Tesla coil then?

Comment: Not applying power would render it safe.